# Can't login to heroku using CLI

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I try to login to heroku on Windows. Using cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\Komp_1\OneDrive\PHP_projects\chatbot>heroku auth:login
Enter your Heroku credentials:
Email: sergiuszxxxi@gmail.com
Password: **********
Enter your Heroku credentials:
Email: sergiuszxxxi@gmail.com
Password: **********
Enter your Heroku credentials:
Email:
```

It looks like a never ending loop. But when I try use a git-bash to login than:

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials:
Email: Sergiusxxxi@gmail.com
 !    Login is currently incompatible with git bash/Cygwin/MinGW
```

What can be wrong? I can't find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so probably that was problem from Heroku. Simple steps to repair this:
1. Go to heroku
2. Log out
3. Reset password
4. Go to your email and set up new password
5. Login to your heroku :-)

PS. My password was correct and I used this same in cmd and on heroku. On heroku worked but in cmd not :-)

Comment: My case seem like having other soft keyboard layout and result different symbol when I login website then cmd... That why it fail..

Answer (score 11):

From Git Bash try using ***winpty heroku login*** and it will work

Comment: Finally found a solution after a day! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows machine solved this by installing Heroku CLI from win installer [enter link description here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install)

Before that I've installed this by npm.

P.s.

Solution from @Vishal

> From Git Bash try using winpty heroku login and it will work

didn't worked because heroku was not defined in PATH